# In Kubernetes, I'm not seeing SystemOOM messages in events - instead I'm getting an error message in kubelet

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, kubelet

A process on my K8s host is being killed by oomkiller. Occasionally I get the following logged in K8s events (I want to see this):

```
2021-03-16 16:55:23.000000 events  WARN  count = 1 type = DELETED name = boutique2.166cf7e33013b8a8 kind = Node name = boutique2 uid = boutique2 reason = SystemOOM msg = System OOM encountered
```

But most of the time, I don't get the SystemOOm message, but get this in kubelet instead:

```
2021-03-17 08:43:06.405000 kubelet  W  4081 oomparser.go:173]  error reading /dev/kmsg: read /dev/kmsg: broken pipe

2021-03-17 08:43:06.405000 kubelet  E  4081 oomparser.go:149]  exiting analyzeLines. OOM events will not be reported.
```

My logs are being collected by fluentd. Any ideas why I am not always seeing a SystemOOM event being logged?

I am using minikube for this environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell if first set of logs is from `$ kubectl get events` and the second is from `kubelet`? Also could you tell which minikube version are you using and attach the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You are correct. The first can be seen with $ kubectl get events ----all-namespaces and the second is from kubelet. What I've done to simulate this is spun up our app and run a C program that allocates memory until the kernel kills it (essentially it uses malloc to continually allocate 1MiB blocks. Minikube is version is  1.18.1. K8s version is 1.20.2.